# Intermediate model Django ORM

Tags: django, code-snippets, django-orm

I create my manager garages and cars.
I'm trying to count the monetary value of all the cars that are currently in the garage.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField()    

class GarageCar(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    how_much = models.IntegerField()

class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Garage_Name", max_length=30)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('GarageCar', blank=True, null=True)
```

I try something like this:

```
def price_of_cars(request):

    garages = Garage.objects.filter(..) #

    total_price_of_cars_in_this_garages = 0
    for a in garages:
        for p in garages.cars:
            total_price_of_cars_in_this_garages += (p.price * how_much)


    return render_to_response('garage.html',
    {'total_price_of_cars': total_price_of_cars_in_this_garages})
```

but return: syntax error and if I delete `how_much` return error: **'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your naming system is very confusing.
`garage.cars` is confusing because there is a car model, but it means a different model. 
`how_much` is confusing because I think you mean `quantity` though it looks like it should be a price.

That said, the first error you get will be because `how_much` is not in the scope of `price_of_cars`. It's a property of the `GarageCars` model.

Next up, you can't iterate through `cars` like that, it's a manager. You'll have to use `cars.all()` or `cars.filter(..)` etc

Finally, `price` isn't a property of `cars`, which is a `GarageCar` object not a `Car` object (see how I said the names were making it more confusing?) So we need to change `p.price` to `p.car.price`.

So putting that together, you should get something like this:

```
def price_of_cars(request):
    garages = Garage.objects.filter(..) #

    total_price_of_cars_in_this_garages = 0
    for a in garages:
        for p in garages.cars.all():   # changed to use .all()
            total_price_of_cars_in_this_garages += (p.car.price * p.how_much) # changed to use correct properties (hopefully!)
```